# google analytics Scheduled report Name change

Tags: google-analytics

I am creating the Google Analytics custom scheduled report. But I need to give a specified name to the scheduled report. However Google is adding its own timestamp and name to its report. Is there any way I can change the report's name?

I have tried by giving when generating the custom report that also didn't help.

Example:Analytics All Web Site Data **Daily-Visits-data** 20171014-20171014.csv

I need only Daily-Visits-data as my report name.

Comment: You can't change the name. However you could set up a report in Google Data Studio and name it whatever you like, and then share it with your Stakeholders.

Comment: can we schedule it also from Google Data Studio???

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom report by consuming google analytics reporting API service,Create your own program to pull, generate report and schedule the report with any name you want.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/#introduction